# Python: extracting specific values out an numpy array of indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, filter

I have a numpy array of indices. For example:

```
 indices = np.array([0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 9, 12, 13, 14])
```

I would like to make an array

```
signals = np.zeros(np.amax(indices) + 1)
```

where I put a value of 2.0 for the beginning index of a sequence of the form: 0, 1, 2, 3 or 8, 9, 10, 11 (so where the value increases 1) and the last element of this sequence to be 3.0.

If the sequence is only a single number long (so no sequence) I would put the value 4.0 in this array.

So for the example given above the output should be `[2.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 0, 0, 2.0, 3.0, 0, 4.0, 0, 0, 2.0, 0, 3.0]`.

Comment: Normally, you must put your ways that you have tried, in the body of your question. Consider this for your next questions.

Comment: If you don't want downvotes, include your effort.  Wordy descriptions tend to be ambiguous, or at least hard to follow.  It's much easier to understand and improve working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of issues, usually, can be handled by `np.diff`. We need to find starting and ending indices of each sequence; Also, the index of the value that is not in any sequences to be removed from indices that are found. At the end, the `signals` will be filled, in the specified `indices`, by the specified values:

```
# append is used for considering the last element
diff1 = np.diff(indices, prepend=indices[0]-2, append=indices[-1]+2)          # [2 1 1 4 1 2 3 1 1 2]
mask_start = diff1 != 1               # [ True False False  True False  True  True False False  True]
end = np.where(mask_start)[0] - 1     # [-1  2  4  5  8]

# correcting start mask for where a value is not in a sequence
mask4 = np.diff(end, prepend=end[0]-2) == 1
mask4_ind = end[mask4]
mask_start[mask4_ind] = False         # [ True False False  True False False  True False False  True]

# modifying the zero array
signals_copy = signals[indices]
signals_copy[mask_start[:-1]] = 2.0
signals_copy[end[1:]] = 3.0
signals_copy[mask4_ind] = 4.0
signals[indices] = signals_copy
```

This code is worked on your example and is tested on some others. You can cure this code if you encounter any probable shortcomings.